# Can't access HTML input controls created in code behind in a literal

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I have an aspx page and added a literal control:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ControlLiteral"></asp:Literal>
```

Then, in codebehind I'm using a for sentence to massively create controls, the idea is something like this:

```
ControlLiteral.Text = @"<input  id=""txtMaterial1"" type=""text"" value=""escribe un valor"" disabled=""disabled"" onclick=""somefunction(this)"" style=""width:250px;"" />
```

then I want to get the value after a submit button in codebehind, but  problem is I can't find them and I'm starting to think that codebehind is not aware of those controls even though I check the HTML source code and everything is there so...  any ideas?

I have tried the following:

1. added the runat="server" in the string that creates the control, but of course, it doesn't work, it just added that text runat="server"  in the html
2. Request.Form["txtMaterial"] or Request["txtMaterial"]  finds nothing
3. Page.Controls.Find("txtMaterial") returns null
4. When I do this, this.from1.Controls.Count  it retrieves only 11 controls isntead of the 210  controls I added in the for statement,  and if retrieve them like this this.from1.Controls[2], those irrelevant html tags created by the asp.net engine
5. Page.Controls.Count  retrieves only 5 controls

Those controls are inside a table, dont know it that has something to do, so, do you have any ideas, it's been a while since the last time I used asp.net but remember that this was possible, please let my know your ideas,

Comment: You can't create server controls by setting the text of a Literal. It's not compiled like it would be if you added it into the .aspx/ascx file.

Comment: Instead of adding the code like that, you should have a Panel or other place holder where you add your new control to the Controls collection of the place holder. This should be done in Page_Init so that the controls are properly registered for postbacks.

Comment: @rossisdead those are not server controls, they are HTML controls...

Answer (score -1):

Try using `submit` to call a function in the javascript.

```
__doPostBack(controlid,json.stringify())
```

example:

```
$scope.btn_generatepdf = function () {
      var myJSON = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.elements.length; i++) {
           myJSON = myJSON + ($scope.elements[i].value) + '|';
      }
      alert(myJSON);

     __doPostBack('btn_generatepdf1', myJSON);
}
```

codebehind page_load:

```
if (page.ispostback)
{
     string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
     string[] allParams = parameter.Split('|');
     string val = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't seem even remotely relevant to the question.